# kendo grid does not show some columns when too much width

Tags: html, css, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In my angular project I am using kendo grid. it looks like this:

[image]

And here is the relevant code. html:

```
<mat-card class="f-layoutcard lage-table">
      <kendo-grid
        class="f-table f-searchable"
        [data]="mitarbeiterListForKendoGrid"
        [loading]="loading$ | async"
        [scrollable]="'scrollable'"
        [selectable]="selectableSettings"
        #kendoGridInstance="kendoGrid"
      >
        <kendo-grid-column field="name" title="Nutzername" [width]="150">
        </kendo-grid-column>

        <kendo-grid-column field="vorname" title="Vorname" [width]="150">
        </kendo-grid-column>

        <kendo-grid-column field="nachname" title="Nachname" [width]="150">
        </kendo-grid-column>

        <kendo-grid-column
          field="einsatzOeName"
          title="Einsatz-OE"
          [width]="150"
        >
        </kendo-grid-column>

        <kendo-grid-column
          field="dienstgradName"
          title="Dienstgrad"
          [width]="150"
        >
        </kendo-grid-column>

        <kendo-grid-column
          field="baoStandardFunktionName"
          title="Standardfunktion"
          [width]="150"
        >
        </kendo-grid-column>

        <kendo-grid-column
          field="name"
          title="BAO-Organisation"
          [width]="150"
        >
        </kendo-grid-column>

        <kendo-grid-column field="name" title="Aktion" [width]="150">
        </kendo-grid-column>

        <sh-util-kendo-grid-custom-messages>
        </sh-util-kendo-grid-custom-messages>
        <kendo-grid-messages
          noRecords="Keine Datensätze verfügbar."
        ></kendo-grid-messages>
      </kendo-grid>
    </mat-card>
```

CSS:

```
.lage-table {
  overflow-x: scroll; // my goal here was to make the grid horizontally scrollable
}

::ng-deep .f-table {
  min-width: 100%;
}
```

Notice that the first visible column is "Nachname". But it should start with "Nutzername" and "Vorname".

If I remove the width from all columns, all columns will be visible (but squashed). Thats why I added the width and the CSS to fit everything.

But after setting the width, I can see the real first two columns in the developer console on the left side, outside of the element.

I wonder why it is so and hope someone can help to fix it, so that every column will be shown.

EDIT: Maybe I should mention that this is the screen:

[image]

Comment: css scroll should be addd on .k-grid-content not the .lage-table

Comment: @SonuSindhu just tried it out, same result but now the design got ugly also

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it with css. Rely on the kendo component and read the [docs](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/width/):

*"When all column widths are explicitly set and the cumulative column width is greater than the available Grid width, a horizontal scrollbar appears and all set column widths are respected."*

Comment: i just tried that, same result, always the 6 out of 8 columns are shown

Answer (score 0):

I found the error. The reason why some columns were not visible, was because somehow the width of the columns was exceeding the kendo-grid.

The underlying problem was an in-built CSS in the kendo-grid `align-items: center`.

By changing that line to `align-items: baseline`, the problem was fixed.